# Android adaptive icon only?

Tags: android, android-studio, adaptive-icon

We are making an app that has minSdk version 26, the version that started using [Android adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive). Image Asset Studio google recommends creating a lot of legacy icons etc. Is it possible to remove everything and just have an adaptive icon? What folder would that be in then, still mipmap-anydpi-v26? I have tried removing other files but in some Samsung phones I just get the android robot icon

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to not generate Round and Legacy icons like this.
[image]

And you can move both ic_foreground and ic_background to drawable-v26, delete drawable-v24. So your drawable folder is used for other Drawables.
And your mipmap-anydpi-v26 is used for icon_launcher_xml to select foreground and background adaptive drawables stored in drawable-v26 folder.
[image]